# how do I display the maximum value via aggregate functions max and sum?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sum, max

How do I display the record which yields the maximum revenue earned by the many employees. I believe aggregate functions 'MAX' & 'SUM' may be applied but I cannot get it right. Ultimately, I do not wish the display the column 'most_revenue'. 2 tables are involved. I am happy to provide more info if needed.

The following is my attempt and it works, but not according to what I need:

```
SELECT TOP (1) pa.personID, pa.nric, SUM(gd.bookingFee) AS most_revenue
FROM Person_Emp AS pa
INNER JOIN Geo_Date AS gd
ON (pa.personID = gd.employeeID)
GROUP BY pa.personID, pa.nric
;
```

Table Structure & sample data,
Geo_Date relation:

```
dateID  |  bookingFee  |  employeeID
   1           25             16
   2           10             17
   3           15             17
   4           20             17
  ...
```

Person_Emp relation

```
personID    |     NRIC
16          |  3453535345         
17          |  1231312
18          |  13413413
19          |  123434411
20          |  12312312
```

Therefore, I have to display a 'Person Employee' who generated the most revenue, which should be personID '17' in this case, where he earned a total of $45 as compared to personID '16'.

Of course, I will need to sum up the total revenue earned by each personID before I can confirm the highest amount earned amongst others. Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide the table structure, some sample input data and desired output.

Comment: Thank you jpw, ive done the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server 2012 you can use a window function like `rank()` to do this.

```
select personID 
from (
    select personID, rank() over (order by sum(bookingFee) desc) sales_rank
    from person_emp pe
    left join geo_date gd on pe.personID = gd.employeeID
    group by personID
) data
where sales_rank = 1
```

If you had multiple persons with the same total they would all get rank 1 and be returned.

Or using just `max()` and `sum()` and no window function:

```
select pe.personID
from person_emp pe
left join geo_date gd on pe.personID = gd.employeeID
group by pe.personID
having sum(bookingfee) = (
    select max(sum_of_bookingfee) 
    from (
       select employeeID, sum(bookingFee) sum_of_bookingfee 
       from geo_date 
       group by employeeID
    ) data
)
```